# Closest location using Google Maps for ExpressionEngine

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I am using Google Maps for ExpressionEngine for a store locator but need to build some additional functionality for a small area on my home page.

I need to show the closest store location on a map using the visitor's current location and also list out the details of the closest store (title, address, distance from closest location, etc).

Google Maps for ExpressionEngine does not do this out of the box and I'm unsure how to achieve this.

I know the {exp:gmap:current_location} tag will draw out a map with the visitor's location, but I don't know how to get the rest to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Essentially, you just need some JS to create a new LatLngBounds object. Then you need to add the current location and the first X markers to that bounds, then use fitToBounds() method to set the map to your newly created bounds. If I get time today or this week, I will write the code for this. But just wanted to post this here in the meantime.

Comment: The code help would be wonderful and much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to check back in with you to see if you were going to be able to put some code together for this. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a month. Any plans to get to this?